# Android Muti Selected GridView Item

Tags: android, gridview, multi-select

I want to select gridview item like gallery. First time i select using itemLongClickListenr then select only one time tap on other items that would be delete. Just like gallery image selection and then delete multiple images. How can i do this. Any Suggestion ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar task. I did as follows:

1-Create custom adapter.

2-implement item click listener and long item click listener.

3-on long item click listener, enable selection of items.

4-when selection is enabled, use item click listener to set property of selection of object to selected/unselected from data array.

5- upon delete button click, check your data array and remove items with selected property.

6-notify adapter about data changed.

That's all. here is code that I used, modify it to achieve your tasks.

```
public class FavoriteGVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FavoriteObject> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<FavoriteObject> data = new ArrayList<FavoriteObject>();
boolean editable;

public FavoriteGVAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                         ArrayList<FavoriteObject> data, boolean editable) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.editable=editable;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.titleTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
        holder.subtitleTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.subtitleTV);
        holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.delete_btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        holder.edit_btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.edit_btn);
        row.setTag(holder);
        row.setId(position);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
    }

    FavoriteObject item = data.get(position);
    holder.titleTV.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.subtitleTV.setText(item.getPallets().size()+" Swatches");
    try{
        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources()
                .getIdentifier(item.getImageName(), "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        holder.imageItem.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }catch (Exception e){
        holder.imageItem.setImageDrawable(null);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (editable){
        holder.edit_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.edit_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnEditItemClick(position));
    }else {
        holder.edit_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClick(position));
        row.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClick(position));
    }
    return row;

}

static class Holder {
    TextView titleTV,subtitleTV;
    ImageView imageItem;
    Button edit_btn,delete_btn;

}
private class OnLongClick implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnLongClick(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
        if (((Activity) context) instanceof FavoritesActivity) {
            ((FavoritesActivity) context).onFavoriteItemLongClick(mPosition);
        }
        return true;
    }
};
private class OnItemClick implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClick(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (((Activity) context) instanceof FavoritesActivity) {
            ((FavoritesActivity) context).onFavoriteItemClick(mPosition);
        }
    }
};
private class OnEditItemClick implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnEditItemClick(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (((Activity) context) instanceof FavoritesActivity) {
            ((FavoritesActivity) context).onFavoriteItemEditClick(mPosition);
        }
    }
};
```

}

In your activity use this:

```
 public void onFavoriteItemClick(int mPosition)
{
    if (editing){
        gridArray.get(mPosition).selectItem(true);
        CMAppManager.getInstance().saveFavoritesData(this, gridArray);
        customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
public void onFavoriteItemLongClick(int mPosition)
{
    editing=true;
    customGridAdapter = new FavoriteGVAdapter(this, R.layout.favorite_item, gridArray,(save_pallet)?false:true);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
}
```

Then on delete button click, remove the selected items from adapter array and notify adapter.

Comment: why u use this, OnEditItemClick

Comment: remove this. I used it for another button event click on the item.

Comment: also you used editing in condition in activity. why?

Comment: editing is set true on Long Item Click. when you long press on an item, then selection is enabled,otherwise simple item click to do whats needed

Comment: code is just to give you idea. I mentioned you the steps at the beginning for achieving the task. That should work for you.

Comment: done. but how can i highlight selected item? any idea?

Comment: use an image or border with color. for selected items make image visible or change color of border on delete button click by calling notifyDataSetChanged().